In-line APA reference for webpage from an institution
Insofar as I can see the following is a valid APA reference to a website I'm referencing in a school paper:

American Academy of Pediatrics. (2021, October 19). Aap-AACAP-Cha Declaration of a national emergency in child and Adolescent Mental Health. https://www.aap.org/en/advocacy/child-and-adolescent-healthy-mental-development/aap-aacap-cha-declaration-of-a-national-emergency-in-child-and-adolescent-mental-health

When referencing this inline should I write "(American Academy of Pediatrics, 2021)", or could I write "(AAP, 2021)", since AAP is a well-known acronym for that organization? The first option seems a bit ... wordy ...

This is what APA says:

If the group name first appears in a narrative citation, include the abbreviation before the year in parentheses, separated with a comma.

The American Psychological Association (APA, 2017) provided information on overcoming opioid abuse.

If the group name first appears in a parenthetical citation, include the abbreviation in square brackets, followed by a comma and the year.

People can overcome opioid abuse through residential treatment (American Psychological Association [APA], 2017).


In other words, use (American Academy of Pediatrics [AAP], 20xx) on first reference, and (AAP, 20xx) thereafter.
